# Rewrite except loading JS files

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

In my nginx setting, I have the following rewritting

```
location ~* ^/1/\b(?!#|auth)\w+\b/? {
    rewrite ^/1/(.*)$ https://www.funfun.io/1/#/$1 redirect;
}
```

As a result, `www.funfun.io/1/home` will be rewritten to `www.funfun.io/1/#/home`, which is what I want.

However, `www.funfun.io/1/3.bundle.js` will be written to `www.funfun.io/1/#/3.bundle.js` too, which is NOT what I want. I want to leave `www.funfun.io/1/3.bundle.js`, more generally `www.funfun.io/1/*.js`, as it is.

Does anyone know how to specify that in the nginx block?

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude the sequence in the rewrite.

Something like this should work:

```
rewrite ^/1/(.*[^.][^j][^s])$ https://www.funfun.io/1/#/$1 redirect;
```

Comment: it works... now I want to rewrite `www.funfun.io/1/*.js` to `www.funfun.io/bundles/*.js`, do you know how to write this?

Comment: Put another rewrite before, with the last keyword: rewrite ^/1/(.*[.]js)$ https://www.funfun.io/bundles/$1 redirect last; It should work

Comment: why `redirect last`? it gave an error for `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: Sorry just a typo. You can try one or the other.